# Set date modified of files in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, filesystems

How can I set the date modified attribute of a file in Cocoa? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about `NSFileManager` `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Attributes are a dictionary. You can set a modification date value with the `NSFileModificationDate` key.

Basically:

```
NSDictionary* attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: yourDate, NSFileModificationDate, NULL];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes: attr ofItemAtPath: yourPath error: NULL];
```