# How to set attributesOfItemAtPath (such as modification date/time) on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, asihttprequest, last-modified

I know I can use `attributesOfItemAtPath` to get modification time/date of file among other things... but is there a way to SET the modification date/time of a file?

I have looked at [How to set the modification time of a file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185338/how-to-set-the-modification-time-of-a-file-programmatically) but it does not seem to apply.

The reason I ask is I use http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ (as below) to fetch a file... however the timestamp is not kept the same as the Last-Modified time on the server.  I want to use the Last-Modified header to set the date/time of the downloaded file so i can keep the downloaded time on my system the same as it is on the server.

My code follows:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *requestFeed = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kGZipSQLURL]];
[requestFeed setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[requestFeed setDownloadDestinationPath:librarySQLGZipPath];
[requestFeed setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
[requestFeed setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[requestFeed setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*30];
[requestFeed setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[requestFeed startSynchronous];
NSString *lastModified = [[requestFeed responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
NSLog(@"Last Modified: %@",lastModified);
```

So, the string `lastModified` holds the time/date stamp.  Is there a way to ensure that the file at `librarySQLGZipPath` will now be set to the date/time in `lastModified`?  Using the current method, the file `librarySQLGZipPath` holds the time it was downloaded, which to me is invalid.

Thanks!

Jann

***EDIT LATER:***

Because I wanted to nicely put on this page how to do the code for this and still wanted to give Steven Kramer credit for answering I am now gonna edit the question with the answer I got using code:

whereas `NSDateFromRFC1123` is a routine found here: http://blog.mro.name/2009/08/nsdateformatter-http-header/ (with some adjustments) to change the Last-Modified header string into a NSDate object:

```
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self NSDateFromRFC1123:lastModified]  ,NSFileModificationDate, nil];
NSError *errorFile;
if ([NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:attrs ofItemAtPath:librarySQLGZipPath error: &errorFile])
{
NSLog(@"Set timestamp of file");
}
else {
NSLog(@"COULD NOT set timestamp of file");
}
```

**Thanks so much Steven!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-[NSFileManager setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes ofItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error`

Comment: Ahh .. something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791148/set-date-modified-of-files-in-cocoa  (This did NOT come up in search cos i put in iPhone)  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Checkmark and +1

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be just the the ticket ;-)